# gaussian process regression hyperparameter optimizatian Manual tuning vs Automatic parameter tuning

Tags: gaussian-process, hyperparameter

When the Gaussian process uses the ard kernel, if the feature is very obvious, but the prior knowledge knows that this feature is not very important, when using the marginal likelihood function to optimize the hyperparameters, the lengthscale of this feature will be optimized to a very small size. If you manually change the hyperparameters, Increasing the lengthscale of this feature will result in a very small variance of prediction. How to deal with such a problem!

Comment: It's not clear from your description what the problem is.

Comment: What I mean is that a certain feature of a sampling point is not important, but after optimizing the hyperparameters through the matlab fitrgp toolbox, the lengthscale of this feature is particularly small. Can it be understood that the feature is important? Should I manually adjust the lengthscale of this feature?